# Plotly boxplot outliners not getting rendered properly

Tags: angular, plotly, boxplot

I am trying to display `boxplot` in Angular 6 app using `Plotly.js.` I am having problem with my generated graph. I want only the box and lines to be displayed in the graph and not the points. So I have set '`boxpoints`' to '`outliners'` in my data array. I have around 10 arrays for which I have to display boxplot. The generated graph contains lines for some of the data and point for some other. I need to generate the graph with only boxes(outliers). Here is image of generated Boxplot.

[image: generated Boxplot]

Thanks in advance

Comment: I found the solution. Instead of setting 'boxpoints' property to 'outliners', I just had to set it to false.

Comment: Please post as answer then. :)

Comment: It's not allowing me to set my own comment as an answer

Comment: Yeah, because you must paste your comment to the answer field, post the answer to your question and accept it thereafter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Instead of setting 'boxpoints' property to 'outliners', I just had to set it to false